Django session key not found using str(instance.id)
This is my scenario I have a signal on cart apps which is raised when admin delete a product in Django but searching for the product key in the session is not working below is the code that I'm using
from django.db.models.signals import post_delete
from django.dispatch import receiver
from store.models import Product
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session

@receiver(post_delete, sender=Product)
def update_cart_on_product_delete(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    # Get all sessions
      

    for session in Session.objects.all():
        data = session.get_decoded()
       
   
        print(data)
        if str(instance.id) in data:
            print(f"Instance ID {instance.id} found in cart")         
            print(instance.id)
            del data[str(instance.id)]
            session['cart'] = data
            session.save()
        else:
            print(f"Instance ID {instance.id} not found in cart") 

And on the terminal when I get the result it appear like this
{'session_key': {'47': 1}}
Instance ID 47 not found in cart

as you can see clear the INSTANCE.ID is in the cart '47' but django code is not able to find it even that I'm converting the key to str.

Given I understand it correctly, the this is data in the cart of the key, so:
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
from django.db.models.signals import post_delete
from django.dispatch import receiver
from store.models import Product


@receiver(post_delete, sender=Product)
def update_cart_on_product_delete(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    key = str(instance.id)
    missing = object()
    updated_sessions = []
    for session in Session.objects.all():
        data = session.get_decoded()['cart']  # 🖘 cart lookup
        if data.pop(key, missing) is not missing:
            session['cart'] = data
            updated_sessions.append(session)
    Session.objects.bulk_update(updated_sessions, fields=('session_data',))
We here also update these Session objects in bulk with .bulk_update(…) [Django-doc].
But signals are often an antipattern [django-antipatterns]. Indeed, signals for example don't run if you do operations in bulk. Typically it is better to look for logic that does not rely on signals. Disclosure: I am the author of that page.

Sorry this signal is not running in bulk. The signal is executed when admin delete a product in Django Admin, the signal is sent after delete (post delete) with the exact product that admin just deleted. The signal is executed exactly at the time that I need it but when looking for the deleted product ID is not finding the product id in the cart even the product id been in the cart as I show in here and even I'm converting the product ID to str in my code as you can see in here.

@JosePerez: you can't know that it will not later do that in bulk. Indeed, if you for example select multiple objects in the admin, and run the delete action. Or if you have a view with Product.objects.filter(expired=True).delete(). Another scenario is where a models.CASCADE, for example if the Product has a category and you remove that Category.

But regardless, I don't think it makes much sense to proactively change session data: it will also introduce race conditions where you thus remove items from a session while meanwhile a certain person might change the corresponding session. A more robust way is probably just if you need the cart, to fetch the Products along, and if products are missing in the fetch, remove these from the session. This makes the operation idempotent, and furthermore more efficient, since we don't need to manipulate sessions no longer in use.

Sorry guys I'm a beginner in Django and I just read the signal is the best way to do this. That's the reason why I'm using signal and again I just need all the sessions that have that specific product that's is getting deled by admin get updated once product get deleted doing so the shopping cart icon will show up the right amount on each cart.

@JosePerez: well that's strange, because the Django documentation itself warns against using this, as well as a lot of painful coding episodes.
